# Detecting background tap

Tags: objective-c

I'm busy with an app you need to touch a button, but when u touch outside the button (on the background of the app screen) i want to display an alert.

Does anyone know how to detect an tap on the background

Button:

```
   MyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    MyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [MyButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tap.png"] forState:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:MyButton];

    [MyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a gesture recogniser to the view.

E.g.

```
// in viewDidLoad:
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)backgroundTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // display alert
}
```

What you could also try is having a full size `UIView` behind the button that has a gesture recogniser on it:

```
// in viewDidLoad:
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
backgroundView.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)backgroundTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // display alert
}
```

This might work better than adding the gesture recogniser to `self.view`.

Comment: In backgroundtapped i placed a NSlog and when i'm touch my button the alert (nslog) shows up..i touched the button and not the background?

Comment: Hmm I was wondering about that, although I'm slightly surprised as I've done a similar thing before and it worked. I need to have a think and build a test...

Comment: The uibutton is programmatically scripted. No interface builder. In html you can use z-index things is this also possible in objective-c?

Comment: No z-index stuff no. If you're seeing the button, then it's "above" the background already.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom subclass of a UIView, make it transparent but with touch handlers, and place a full size instance of that new view subclass underneath your button.  You can then have that subview send a message to your main view controller (via delegation) whenever it see a touch down event.  Since the button is on top of this subview, the subview won't do anything if the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the solution in the first answer and tested it. It did not work for me. The gesture recognizer captured my button & other UI element touches (I'm loading from nib)

```
    A window delivers touch events to a gesture recognizer before it delivers
    them to the hit-tested view attached to the gesture recognizer. Generally,
    if a gesture recognizer analyzes the stream of touches in a multi-touch 
    sequence and does not recognize its gesture, the view receives the full
    complement of touches
```

I used a slightly different solution:

```
UIButton *invisibleBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
invisibleBtn.titleLabel.text = @"";
invisibleBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // no tap events if this is not set, bizarre
[invisibleBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:invisibleBtn];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:invisibleBtn];
```